# Why isn't photosynthesis catabolic reaction?

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology

Here is the chemical equation of photosynthesis

$$CO_2 + H_{2}O \longrightarrow C_{6}H_{12}O_{6} + O_2 $$

We see that the water is in reactant side of the equation. By the way, It ought to be catabolic reaction. However, It seems anabolic reaction on my textbook.

- What should we think for this reaction?
- How do we get If energy turned out in product side of the equation?
- Why isn't photosynthesis catabolic reaction?

Comment: How do you define catabolic reactions in the first place? From what I see, the only thing I could say is _"water on the reactant side != hydrolysis"_

Comment: @another'Homosapien' That's my bad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catabolic and Anabolic Reactions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/67442/catabolic-and-anabolic-reactions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catabolic reactions are those that make larger/more complex molecules into those that are smaller/less complex, releasing energy.

Anabolic reactions are those that makes smaller/less complex molecules into those that are larger/more complex, costing energy.

Photosynthesis takes two of the least complex molecules from the perspective of biology, carbon dioxide and water, and forms glucose which is high-energy and complex - this is clearly an anabolic reaction.

The only way I can interpret your question is that you were misunderstanding the definitions of catabolic and anabolic.